# Spring AMQP RabbitMQ does not consume all messages, workers finish prematurely

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am struggling to find proper setting to delay timeout for workers in `RabbitMQ`.

By default `prefetchCount` since the version `2.0` are set to 250 and exactly this amount of messages are being received and processed.
I would like to keep workers busy, until they clear up an entire queue (lets say 10k messages).

I can manipulate this number manually, such as changing default limit or assigning more threads resulting in multiplying default number.

Results are always the same. Once the number is reached, workers stop their job and application finish its execution

`o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.`

I would like them to finish when the queue is empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `logger.info("Successfully waited for workers to finish.");` happens only in one place - `doShutdown()`. And this one is called from the `shutdown()`, which is called from the `destroy()` or `stop()`.

I somehow think that you exit from your application by some reason. You just don't block the `main()` to work permanently.

Please, share a simple project we can play with.

Comment: When you figure out why your app is being stopped prematurely, you can listen for `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`s by setting the `idleEventInterval` - the event will be published if the queue remains empty for that period. See [Detecting Idle Asynchronous Consumers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#idle-containers),

Comment: Nothing happens really apart from message processing. `main()` is empty, I do not override any default methods. I configure using single annotation `@RabbitListener(queues = queueName)`

Comment: Well, then it is definitely needs some code from you to let us to play with. Thanks

Comment: I accepted answer, because even for a blind shot you were right. Main method was interrupted. 
   `SpringApplication.run(NxcsEventProcessor.class, args).close();` which was poor copypaste results from rabbitmq docs. My collegue from work noticed that

Comment: So, the `main()` wasn't empty after all ;-)